# Which layout is best for showing horizontal items in android

Tags: android

I need to show one image and 3 textview and one radio button  horizontally in android which layout using will be best that is linear layout or relative layout and why??

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `RelativeLayout` will be the better choice. `RadioButton` will probably come at the end right? `RelativeLayout` can do that easily. I'm guessing `ImageView` comes at the left end. And 3 `TextView` in the middle. `RelativeLayout` is a good choice to implement this.

Comment: For 3 textview I have to provide margin left ??

Comment: For different screen width using relative layout won't be an issue??

Comment: put the 3 `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` in the middle. Give `layout_weight=1` for each `TextView`. The width of `LinearLayout` should be `match_parent`, but provide necessary margin to right to avoid overlapping the `RadioButton` on the right. Set `LinearLayout` to alignTo_Rightof `ImageView`

Comment: You mean relative layout as parents and then scroll view and then linear layout??

Comment: Not `ScrollView`. Is this view for a list item or for another layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all view in just horizontally and you also don't want to do any more customization then linear layout is good and If you want to more customization then Relative Layout(Customizations means like you want to make one view height based on another view height width or something).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Constraint layout for horizontal aligning of the Views. You can set constraints and give them horizontal bias. Read about constraint layout [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)
.